# Pandas: write data to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have data frame and I want change that and next write it to `json`.

```
                                       ID      month   val
0        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-01    1
1        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-02    0
2        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-03    0
3        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-04    0
4        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-05    0
5        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-06    0
6        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-07    0
7        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08-08    0
8        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-09-09    0
9        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-09-10    0
10       00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-09-11    0
11       00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-09-12    0
```

I need convert that to this

```
ID      month   val
0        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-08    1
1        00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401 2015-09    1
```

If some of day in month == 1, I need write that month == 0. If not, I should write 0, and if since 12.2013 to 30.2016 are not information about some month some, I should write 0.
And next I try to write it to json, I try

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month).dt.to_period('m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

but it only replace data in `month`. 
Next I try `df = df.groupby(['ID', df.month.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')]).agg(lambda v: (v == 1).any().astype(int)).reset_index()` but it doesn't print all month in this interval. 
And try write to json

```
nielson_june = StringIO.StringIO()
d = df.groupby('ID')['month', 'val'].apply(lambda x:   pd.Series(x.set_index('month')['val'].to_dict())).to_json(nielson_june, orient='index')
with open('nielsen-telecom','w') as f:
   json.dump(json.loads(nielson_june.getvalue()), f, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is wrong with `pandas.DataFrame.to_json`?

Comment: First I need to change this df. I need if there are no strings with month from 12.2013 to 06.2016, write this month with val == 0  @ChE

Comment: Yes, I understand this. My comment was refering to second part "_and next write it to json._" of your question.

Comment: Use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to get your dates correct, then use whatever you want to format your data however you want, then use `to_json`